# Why do I get NullPointerException when using org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout to generate DI information for my bpmn file without it?

Tags: java, xml, activiti, bpmn

May I ask you a question about using the BpmnAutoLayout class in the maven dependency activiti-bpmn-layout?

I programatically created an XML format .bpmn file without DI information (bpmnWithoutDI.bpmn) using activiti-bpmn-model api. I want to use the BpmnAutoLayout class to generate the DI information automatically for my bpmnWithoutDI.bpmn xml file. But when I run my program I get the folloing Exception:

[image: The Exception Info]

Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?

You can download my source code from the following URL:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V9LUZLLZ1c-3JWzcSqDyM7IyywKB7Bvj/view?usp=sharing

It is zip file of an Eclipse maven project containing my java source code and the input file bpmnWithoutDI.bpmn . You can simply import the maven project and run the  AutoLayoutDemo.java to reproduce the exception.

I also include my code below:

AutoLayoutDemo.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

import org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout;
import org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BpmnXMLConverter;
import org.activiti.bpmn.model.BpmnModel;


public class AutoLayoutDemo {

    private BpmnModel convertXmlFileWithoutDIToBpmnModel(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, XMLStreamException {
        InputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(xmlStream, "UTF-8");
        XMLStreamReader xtr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(in);
        return new BpmnXMLConverter().convertToBpmnModel(xtr);
    }

    private void autoLayoutBpmnModel(BpmnModel model) {
        BpmnAutoLayout autoLayout = new BpmnAutoLayout(model);
        autoLayout.execute();
    }

    private void generateXmlFileWithDI(BpmnModel model, String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);



        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            byte[] byteArray = new BpmnXMLConverter().convertToXML(model);
            fos.write(byteArray);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, XMLStreamException {
        AutoLayoutDemo demo = new AutoLayoutDemo();
        BpmnModel model = demo.convertXmlFileWithoutDIToBpmnModel("bpmnWithoutDI.bpmn");
        demo.autoLayoutBpmnModel(model);
        demo.generateXmlFileWithDI(model, "bpmnWithDI.bpmn");
    }

}
```

bpmnWithoutDI.bpmn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="process_dispute_extractor" name="dispute_extractor" isExecutable="true">
    <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" name="STEP extract_urls: This step opens the AVC portal and gathers all the unresolved chargeback urls">
      <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start" name="start"></startEvent>
      <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end" name="end"></endEvent>
      <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></exclusiveGateway>
      <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" name="get the chargeback id">
        <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0" name="Start"></startEvent>
        <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1"></exclusiveGateway>
        <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></exclusiveGateway>
        <serviceTask id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" name="add to the list of urls to process" activiti:delegateExpression="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3implementation"></serviceTask>
        <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4" name="End"></endEvent>
      </subProcess>
      <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></exclusiveGateway>
      <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" name="Send 150 urls to image analyzer process module">
        <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0" name="Start"></startEvent>
        <serviceTask id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" name="JUMP TO image_analyzer" activiti:delegateExpression="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1implementation"></serviceTask>
        <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2" name="End"></endEvent>
      </subProcess>
    </subProcess>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" name="Else" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" name="If the id hasn't been processed" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" name="For each url" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" name="For each time" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" name="Loop over" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end"></sequenceFlow>
    <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-start" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-end" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-start--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-start" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls--process_dispute_extractor-end" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-end"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your correct bpmn file is below , I've changed and test it, I hope this could help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="process_dispute_extractor" name="dispute_extractor" isExecutable="true">
    <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" name="STEP extract_urls: This step opens the AVC portal and gathers all the unresolved chargeback urls">
      <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start" name="start"></startEvent>
      <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end" name="end"></endEvent>
      <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></exclusiveGateway>
      <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" name="get the chargeback id">
        <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0" name="Start"></startEvent>
        <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1"></exclusiveGateway>
        <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></exclusiveGateway>
        <serviceTask id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" name="add to the list of urls to process" activiti:delegateExpression="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3implementation"></serviceTask>
        <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4" name="End"></endEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="xprocess_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" name="If the id hasn't been processed" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3"></sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-3" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2"></sequenceFlow>     
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-1"></sequenceFlow>     
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1-4"></sequenceFlow>     
      </subProcess>
      <exclusiveGateway id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></exclusiveGateway>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" name="For each time" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" name="Loop over" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-start" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-2" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-end"></sequenceFlow>     
      <subProcess id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3" name="Send 150 urls to image analyzer process module">
        <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0" name="Start"></startEvent>
        <serviceTask id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" name="JUMP TO image_analyzer" activiti:delegateExpression="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1implementation"></serviceTask>
        <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2" name="End"></endEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1"></sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-3-2"></sequenceFlow>
      </subProcess>
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" name="For each url" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1"></sequenceFlow>       
      <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-1" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls-0"></sequenceFlow>
    </subProcess>
    <startEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-start" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="process_dispute_extractor-end" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-start--process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-start" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls--process_dispute_extractor-end" sourceRef="process_dispute_extractor-extract_urls" targetRef="process_dispute_extractor-end"></sequenceFlow>

  </process>
</definitions>
```

BPMN exported image:

[image: BPMN exported image]

Comment: Thank you! I also found out what is wrong. The <sequenceFlow> for elements within a subprocess should be placed in that subprocess

Comment: Now I can generate the DI information automatically using the activiti-bpm-layout but the look and feel of its output is not so good. There may be slight overlapping. Actually Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler does an excellent job laying out and display the bpmn file without DI info. It is open source. But I am not able to extract the particular part of source code that does the automatic generation of DI info. I want to extract that code and make a function which read the bpmn file without DI, generate the DI using the code from the modeler, and output a bpmn file with DI. Can you help me with that?

Comment: See [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51829091/3566186)
I'll appreciate very much if you can help me with this!!!

Answer (score 3):

I your code, everything is OK.
the problem is your bpmn file.

I've created a new bpmn file (bpmnWithoutDI2) with xml content :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="User Task"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

Everything is ok and after running code *bpmnWithDI.bpmn* is generated.
But I think the problem is somewhere in *sequenceFlow* elements because without them the code was run successfully.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me more about what is wrong in the my original bpmn file?  I programmatically generate that bpmn file for a process I want to display. So I need to know what is wrong in that BPMN file and correct generation code to display the process. Actually Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler can generate DI info and display a correct diagram for my original bpmn file when I manually  open the bpmn file in Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler. But I cannot extract the particular source code of the modeler for generating the DI info. Thank you!